# Why doesn't Firefox accept different Ports for SSL encryption other than 443

Tags: iis, ssl, webserver, ssl-certificate, firefox

There is an IIS Webserver with different Sites (SSL Binding) because I can't configure IIS to listen on same Address and Port with different Certificates so I set the SSL Port direction in the firewall to another Port of the IIS Webserver IP.

Explanation:

> ```
> Client -> Firewall -> Webserver
> Website1 -> WANIP1:443 -> LANIP1:443
> Website2 -> WANIP2:443 -> LANIP1:444
> ```

So it is possible to encrypt different sites with different certificates on one IIS Webserver. The Problem is now the Browser Firefox (ver.24) if I surf to the Website1 the is a key in the line that show me the Connection is secure, on website2 there is no lock before the URL:

Website1 with the lock:

[image]

Website2 has no lock:

[image]

What is the problem? Nn Safari and IE there is no Problem, what is the difference for Firefox?

**Update:**
I check with different Versions of Browsers. Firefox 3.6 shows the lock-symbol but the current release didn't show this lock-symbol. Is this a error in the current release or is this an error in all other browser? How can I check if the whole traffic is encrypted?

Comment: Did you test it with something such as [this](http://www.digicert.com/help/); also does website2 have any mixed content (http/https)?

Comment: The result of your link is okay no Warnings or Errors. If I change from different Ports to Different IPs all works well. Its only if I use a different local port.

Comment: That makes sense about the IPs. If you have HTTP + HTTPS content on the server FF 23+ will reject it as 'secure'. You might want to check the applicationhost.config manually (if you haven't already) and modify the binding part there. Also make sure you've got SNI checked on.

Comment: The Binding ist Set to Port 444 for website2

Comment: What happens if you change `Website2 -> WANIP2:444 -> LANIP1:444` or set a rewrite from port 443 to port 444. If SNI is on it should've taken care of it properly.

Comment: When I request https://website2:444 than there is no key-symbol, too.